# Finish() is not closing the activity in Oppo device but working as expected on other devices,what is wrong

Tags: android

```
Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        try {
            releaseCamera();
            setResult(RESULT_OK,getIntent().putExtra("image",data));
            finish();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

};
```

I am trying to take picture and sending it back to the activity ,but in Oppo the activity is not closing it is still there like it is hanged nothing is happning.On other phone it is working fine activity is closing and picture is displaying.

```
2018-10-10 16:54:31.108 787-787/? E/HWComposer: prepare: validate failed for display 0: BadDisplay (2)
2018-10-10 16:54:31.108 787-787/? E/SurfaceFlinger: prepareFrame for display 0 failed: -75 (Value too large for defined data type)
2018-10-10 16:54:31.108 787-787/? E/HWComposer: presentAndGetReleaseFences: failed for display 0: NotValidated (7)
2018-10-10 16:54:31.124 787-787/? E/HWComposer: prepare: validate failed for display 0: BadDisplay (2)
2018-10-10 16:54:31.124 787-787/? E/SurfaceFlinger: prepareFrame for display 0 failed: -75 (Value too large for defined data type)
2018-10-10 16:54:31.125 787-787/? E/HWComposer: presentAndGetReleaseFences: failed for display 0: NotValidated (7)
```

logs that i find when i hit capture button .

Comment: Any error in Logs from Oppo device, when Activity gets stuck/hanged. Logs may give us some hint.

Comment: @Jatin how to get Log ,there is no crash . it is just stuck.and when i debug .debugger says application is still running .i think the data that i am passing back is too large, i tied sending a string ,it worked on Oppo as well. what you think it that the problem

Comment: Yes Problem is of Data size. As mentioned in Logs 'prepareFrame for display 0 failed: -75 (Value too large for defined data type)'. You may need to store that data globally, to avoid this situation.

Comment: @jatin then what is the better way to send back the capture image to caller activity?

Comment: You may need to store or keep it at application level. You can create a Model/Data class and store 'byte[] data' in it (in Application class). Or may create a variable in application class and store 'byte[] data' in it. But do reset that variable/model class, once you are done with it.

Answer (score 1):

try `YourActivity.this.finish()`

Comment: tried ,nothing happen .Actually what i observe ,When i comment the setResult line ,the activity is finishing .But i first want to send the result back then finish it.